# In which table in the database are the email messages stored?

Tags: 7, emails

I would like to know what the table the email messages (Emails section at admin/config/people/accounts) are stored in?

Config: Drupal 7

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are stored as system variables in the `{variable}` table, and normally accessed with `variable_get()` and `variable_set()`.  The variable names are

- `user_mail_cancel_confirm_body`
- `user_mail_cancel_confirm_subject`
- `user_mail_password_reset_body`
- `user_mail_password_reset_subject`
- `user_mail_register_admin_created_body`
- `user_mail_register_admin_created_subject`
- `user_mail_register_no_approval_required_body`
- `user_mail_register_no_approval_required_subject`
- `user_mail_register_pending_approval_body`
- `user_mail_register_pending_approval_subject`
- `user_mail_status_activated_body`
- `user_mail_status_activated_notify`
- `user_mail_status_activated_subject`
- `user_mail_status_blocked_body`
- `user_mail_status_blocked_notify`
- `user_mail_status_blocked_subject`
- `user_mail_status_canceled_body`
- `user_mail_status_canceled_notify`
- `user_mail_status_canceled_subject`

Look at the code for `user_admin_settings()`, which is a standard system settings form and has the variable names in it, and `_user_mail_text()` which has all of the default text.